# How to allow the user to input form multiple times before downloading file?

Tags: r, excel, shiny

I would like a user to be able to answer the form multiple times before downloading the file, with each subsequent form added into the excel file.

I've considered a loop with the user able to input how many times through the loop, but I would prefer the user to be able to calculate multiple times, but only need to download the file once. I am not sure where to begin with this. I've also considered shiny modules, but I am not sure that would be the most effective way to complete this. I've included a simplified version:

```
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)
library(openxlsx)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("name","Name"),
  dateInput("date","Birthdate"),
  textInput("title","Title"),
  fileInput("excelfile","Excel File"),
  actionButton("calculate","Calculate"),
  downloadButton("download","Download")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  createcolumns<-observeEvent(input$calculate,{
    age<-year(Sys.Date())-year(input$date)

    df<-data.frame("Name"=input$name,"Age"=age,"Title"=input$title)

    wb<-loadWorkbook(input$excelfile$datapath)
    writeData(wb,"Sheet1",df)
    saveWorkbook(wb,input$excelfile$datapath,overwrite = TRUE)
  })

  output$download<-downloadHandler(
    file = function(){
      filename<-strsplit(input$excelfile$name,"\\.")
      filename<-filename[[1]][1]
      filename<-paste0(filename,"_",Sys.Date())
      paste(filename,"xlsx",sep=".")
    },
    content = function(file){
      file.rename(input$excelfile$datapath,file)
    },
    contentType = "application/xlsx"

  )
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Ideally, the user could input multiple people at once visit, then once everyone was entered, download the completed excel file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by adding a few two variables in the server function (globaldf, x) and moving the bulk of the work into an if statement that checks if the calculate button has increased since the last time.

```
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)
library(openxlsx)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
  column(6,
  textInput("name","Name",value = 1),
  dateInput("date","Birthdate"),
  textInput("title","Title"),
  fileInput("excelfile","Excel File"),
  actionButton("calculate","Calculate"),
  downloadButton("download","Download")
    ),
  column(6,
    h1("Output"),
    tableOutput("data")
         )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  globaldf<-data.frame("Name"=NULL,"Age"=NULL,"Title"=NULL)

  x<-0

  createcolumns<-reactive({
    req(input$name,input$date,input$title,input$excelfile,input$calculate)
    y<-input$calculate
    if(x<y){
      age<-year(Sys.Date())-year(input$date)

      df<-data.frame("Name"=input$name,"Age"=age,"Title"=input$title)

      globaldf<<-rbind(globaldf,df)

      wb<-loadWorkbook(input$excelfile$datapath)
      writeData(wb,"Sheet1",globaldf)
      saveWorkbook(wb,input$excelfile$datapath,overwrite = TRUE)
      x<<-y
      globaldf  
  } else {return()}

  })

  output$data<-renderTable({
    outputtable<-data.frame(createcolumns())
    outputtable

  })

  output$download<-downloadHandler(
    file = function(){
      filename<-strsplit(input$excelfile$name,"\\.")
      filename<-filename[[1]][1]
      filename<-paste0(filename,"_",Sys.Date())
      paste(filename,"xlsx",sep=".")
    },
    content = function(file){
      file.rename(input$excelfile$datapath,file)
    },
    contentType = "application/xlsx"

  )
}
```